Usage and meaning of ようもない in this sentence
手に汗握りようもない泥沼の展開だ
I wonder how the meaning shifts if I used 手に汗握るような or something to that style. I think the ようもない here doesn't really express some inability or not having means to do something, but rather intensifies the situation, which is hinted at by the 泥沼

If you write '手に汗握るような泥沼の展開だ', then '手に汗握るような' somewhat contradicts with '泥沼の展開'. The expression '手に汗握るような' indicates that a situation is so thrilling that you sweat in your fist (i.e., you are in fight-or-flight mode). One would expect the situation is changing drastically and rapidly. On the other hand, '泥沼の展開' indicates a stalemate situation where all the efforts of involved parties fail to resolve their entangled intentions, so that the situation continues to oscillate around the original point for a prolonged time, as if an animal struggles in a muddy pond but can't get out of it.
The originally quoted phrase '手に汗握りようもない' is an emphasized negation of '手に汗握る', meaning that there is no way to sweat in the fist. In other words, the situation is so boring. Therefore, '手に汗握りようもない' has a consistent meaning with '泥沼の展開'.

手に汗握るような implies a fast-paced and close fight. 泥沼 implies a slow-paced (or dragged) and close fight. So the negation seems to apply to the pace part, without creating inconsistency. Without the negation, it will sound self-contradictory.
